# Best way to start using jQuery in a Zend Framework 1.9 application?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-ui

I want to get started working with jQuery in my Zend Framework application but not sure which is the best way to get started. I know I could include the jQuery library just like any other javascript library, but what are the advantages of using ZendX_JQuery, and what are the steps necessary to start using it in my Zend Framework 1.9 application?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to get jQuery working in my 1.9.4 project by following these steps:

Step 1: Copy the ZendX directory to your **library** directory. ZendX can be found in the extras/library directory of your Zend Framework download.

Step 2: Download jQuery and the jQuery UI library from [jqueryui.com](http://www.jqueryui.com/). I chose the UI Lightness theme.

Step 3: Extract the download and rename jquery-ui-1.7.2 to jquery and move to your **public/js** directory.

Step 4: Add these lines to your **bootstrap** file:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
        ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
        ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js');
}
```

Step 5: Now add the jQuery view helper to your **layout** file:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
</head>
```

Step 6: To test that you have everything working, add this line to one of your **view scripts**:

```
Pick your Date: <?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", '', array('defaultDate' => date('Y/m/d', time()))); ?>
```

Now, if you open this page in your browser, there should be a text field. You should be able to click on the text field, which automatically pops up a calendar that has been styled to the UI Lightness theme.

Answer (score 10):

One little **gotcha**:
You have to add the ZendX folder to your **library** directory - the one which also has your **Zend** directory.

```
[your/lib/path]
|
+-Zend
|  |
|  +-(the full thing)
|
+-ZendX
|  |
|  +-JQuery, Db, Console, ...
```

If you miss adding ZendX to your **library** directory, you get lots of errors messages like this:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'  
with message 'Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry; 
used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/: .....
```

---

Another little **gotcha**:
In the code presented by Andrew above, note the important words highlighted:

```
Now add the jQuery view helper to your layout file:
<head>
    <? php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
</head>

To test that you have everything working, add this line to one of your view scripts:  
<code>
Pick your Date: <?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", ..... 
</code>
```

While `$this->jQuery()` must go in the **layout** file so that all pages get jquery functionality, the actual jQuery code must go to the **view file** itself - `application/views/scripts/yourcontroller/youraction.pthml` - **it does not work in the layout with just this simple code**.

Answer (score 8):

The Solution is - >

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
    $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
    $view->headTitle('IMR - BI System');
    $view->env = APPLICATION_ENV;
    $view->baseUrl = Zend_Registry::get('config')->root_path;

    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery/css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css');
    $view->jQuery()->setLocalPath($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js');
    $view->jQuery()->setUiLocalPath($view->baseUrl .'/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js');
    $view->jQuery()->enable();
    $view->jQuery()->uiEnable();
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

    return $view;
}
```

**I just shifted my Code from _initViewHelpers to _initView**

and it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that you have to (or at least I had to) enable the jquery and jquery components in the _initViewHelpers function:

```
$view->jQuery()->enable()
            ->uiEnable();
```

Comment: By enabling jQuery in the Bootstrap, you will be including the jQuery javascript into every page (regardless of whether or not it needs to be included). By using a jQuery form element (for example) it automatically enables jQuery, and includes the necessary javascript. It may be more efficient to only include it when you need it, but it's up to you. You may decide you want to include jQuery on every page.

Answer (score 3):

As **user117640** sad,

I had to enable the jQuery and UI, it can be done in:

bootstrap :

```
//it will enable for all views
$view->jQuery()->enable()->uiEnable();
```

controller::someAction :

```
//JQ enabled for particular view)
$this->view->jQuery()->enable()->uiEnable();
```

view someAction.phtml:

```
//JQ enabled for particular view
<?php $this-jQuery()->enable()->uiEnable(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

include this to ur bootstrap file

```
$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
$view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/Your Public Path/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
               ->setLocalPath('/Your Public Path/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
               ->setUiLocalPath('/Your Public Path/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js');
```

Add this to ur layout

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
</head>
```

and use jQuery UI functions in ur view file:
Pick your Date:

```
<?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", '', array('defaultDate' => date('Y/m/d', time()))); ?>
```