# ZendX date picker example not working

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-ui, zendx

I am rather new to ZendX and I really wanted to get the simple JQuery example on Zend to get working.I have followed the example on the link below but all I get is a plain textbox without any datepicker functionality as I expected.

[Best way to start using jQuery in a Zend Framework 1.9 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616857/best-way-to-start-using-jquery-in-a-zend-framework-1-9-application)

In my bootstrap I have

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
    {   

        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();     

        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
        $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
        $view->headTitle('JQUERY Test');

        //assuming you already have this function in your bootstrap
        //jQuery (using the ui-lightness theme)

        $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
        $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
                        ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
                        ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js');                                            
    }
```

In my layout I have included

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->HeadMeta(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/main.css'); ?>   
    <?php echo $this->render('_javascript.phtml'); ?>
</head>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you call the view helper from
   within your view script, *with valid options*? See [example
   from your refered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616857/best-way-to-start-using-jquery-in-a-zend-framework-1-9-application/1618552#1618552)
2. Did you double check the paths to your local js- & css-files?

Comment: That is the solution I used to do my example but to no avail.Sorry I forgot to specific that link earlier.As for the local files I have cross checked and the paths and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You add `ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);` to _initViewHelpers

Answer (score 0):

i go through application.ini way which works out like this:

```
resources.view.helperPath.ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper = "ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper"
resources.view[] =
pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource = "ZendX/Application/Resource"
resources.jquery.localpath = "/project1/public/jquery/development-bundle/jquery-1.7.1.js"
resources.jquery.stylesheet = "/project1/public/jquery/development-bundle/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"
resources.jquery.uilocalpath = "/project1/public/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.js"
```

I am not sure about bootstrap code but what I got from research is the below code. May be the last three lines will help.

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{   

    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();     

    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
    $view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
    $view->headTitle('JQUERY Test');

    //assuming you already have this function in your bootstrap
    //jQuery (using the ui-lightness theme)

    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
                    ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
                    ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js');

  $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
  $viewRenderer->setView($view);
  Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);                                            
}
```