# zend + jquery doesn't work at all?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, controller, view-helpers

I'm trying to include the jquery helper in my zend project, documentation from zend is kind of ambiguous, it indicates to use a few lines of code in bootstrap but there are quite some functions like `_initDoctype` / `_initView` / `_initViewHelpers` / `_initAutoload` but it doesn't say where exactly i have to paste the provided code. I pasted it in the `_initDoctype` one, is that good enough???

using this line of code is ok so far:

```
$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
```

when adding this line for a js file or for a simple css file the application crashes bad:

```
$view->jQuery()->setLocalPath($view->baseUrl . '/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js');
$view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');`
```

output is a blank page with the following error message:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'
>   with message 'Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry;
>   used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/
>   Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/'

so, oviously trying to add more code like

```
$view->jQuery()->enable();
$view->jQuery()->uiEnable();
```

is simply useless...

I really need this so called "helper" b/c i don't want to load another page, but it's taken a lot of time and every solution I found over the Web simply doesn't work with my app, it's frustrating... this should be something to take like 5 or 10 minutes to implement but i've spent HOURS on this and nothing works!

Question 1: did I choosed the wrong framework...?

I'm starting to think that the old fashion way is better (meaning creating the app with by hand with no framework at all) and focus later on security issues, some comments about this will be great.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Do not put it in the initDoctype method, just put it in your bootstrap file.

Comment: the ZF bootstrap will automatically run any functions that start with `_init`. So you can create your own arbitrary bootstrap methods by simply naming them appropriatly.

Comment: it doesn't work, i need the view object which is within the class and a function...

Comment: 2nd comment make sense but jQuery helper still not working...

Comment: @Andrew any function that start with `_init` trows the same error, using just `public function init()` returns no error at all, but when adding `$this->jQuery();` the same error is thrown once again

Comment: I know it would throw the same error, I just meant you don't have to put your code in the `_initDoctype` function, you could use `_initJqueryPlugins` instead if you wanted to.

Comment: And you have definitely downloaded ZendX, which is not part of the base Zend download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced similar issues trying to get the Zend Framework jQuery helpers set up. Refer to this S.O. answer for the solution: [Best way to start using jQuery in a Zend Framework 1.9 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616857/best-way-to-start-using-jquery-in-a-zend-framework-1-9-application/1618552#1618552)

In regards to your question:

> Did I choose the wrong framework?

It depends. Zend Framework is not bad, but since learning Zend Framework I have discovered Ruby and the Rails framework and I love it. Ruby has a very nice, readable syntax and Rails is much easier to get started using than Zend Framework.

Comment: steps, followed with this result: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry; used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/'

Comment: I haven't used Ruby (yet) just know it's powerful, due to business requirements php is a must for now... thanks for the advice anyway, I'll start learning ruby soon...

Comment: Have you copied the `ZendX` directory into your `library` directory?

Comment: yep, it's copied to the library directory which structure is:

`
library
  > Zend
    > ZendX
      > JQuery
 > Controller
 > Form
 > View
 > Exception.php
 > Form.php
`

"Zend" folder is there according to zend quick start tutorial

Comment: I'm using `protected function _initViewHelpers()` this is the line that causes the error: `$view->jQuery()->addStylesheet($view->baseUrl . '/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');`

Comment: there's your problem. it doesn't go **in** the Zend directory, it goes **next** to it on the same level.

Comment: And your fatal error is caused by the fact that Zend can't find the JQuery plugin because it can't find the ZendX directory. This line registers the plugin: `$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');` Then it is lazily loaded when you call `$view->jQuery`

Comment: that's good to know, zend documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html says to copy the whole folder in the library so i did the same with ZendX, however this line `<?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>` echoes simply nothing which throws a JS error `$("#dp1").datepicker is not a function`

Comment: Make sure you are putting `<?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>` in the `<head>` section of your layout file. This will render the necessary lines of css/javascript in your html.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't an ideal framework in PHP. While Zend is somehow over-enterprisy and hard to master, there is Yii, which is a copy of Rails, which is a good way to start for medium websites.

Comment: I've checked out Yii, seems to be nice and has many of the functionality that zend provides, still relying on zend due to your coment "somehow over-enterprisy" b/c my app is not a common website but an online ERP with a lot of features being developed so your comment makes me think I made a good decision choosing zend