# Get textarea contents before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea by id "compose" and i want to get the data from that textarea before the submit button is pressed. I have another javascript function that will share the information to various other sites based on the user preferences and i need to pass the information in the textarea to that js.

```
function getVal(){
               alert(document.getElementById("compose").value);

           }
```

I am not getting any information and im guessing its because the information is stored else where but i dont know where that is stored.

I am using zend with this and i would like to use jQuery but i cannot get jQuery to work properly with zend. It either wrecks other components on the page or does not work at all. Any suggestions?

**edit:** This is where i am calling getVal(). Its just a link right now as i am trying to get the input into the text area. Then i will insert the found data into my js script.

I attached Zend because the site is made using the zend framework and after a while of stuggling with jquery i didnt want a jquery answer because i would not be able to use it.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVal()">click</a>`

**edit1** It seems the engine im using has dropped jquery support for the version im using.... Thank you for your answers and help

Comment: What does Zend have to do with Javascript???

Comment: Where are you calling the getVal() function? Maybe you could post more of your code?

Comment: Are you using some kind of *Rich Text Editor*? In that case it might be saved somewhere else.

Comment: If its not a *Rich Text Editor* you can get it by `HTMLTextAreaElement.value` property

Comment: I edited to explain what zend has to do with my question. Im using netbeans.

Comment: @user915946 Still what does Zend have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Your javascript is correct and it should return the value in the textarea. Please post your html for the textarea (also check how the text area is rendered esp if you using a framework).

Answer (score 3):

since you tagged this as jquery I assume you use it. In that case, the simplest way would be ...

`$("#compose").val()`

Oh, never mind, I read now that you can't make jquery work?
In that case, did you read this post? [Best way to start using jQuery in a Zend Framework 1.9 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616857/best-way-to-start-using-jquery-in-a-zend-framework-1-9-application)

Comment: jQuery can work for small things such as alert... but it breaks other things and im not sure why. I have been shifting though the zend to try to find out the reason for the error but i haven't come across the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can hi-jack the `submit` event for the form, do your AJAX request, then submit the form normally:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
         url  : '<URL>',
         data : { compose : $('#compose').val() }
    });
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

Docs for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on